# selective get and delete posts from database

Tags: c#, database, silverlight, windows-phone-7, sqlmetal

In my windows phone 7 app i have database-class generated by sqlmetal.
in addition, i have class that helps to work with this database.

```
    public static IList<Task> GetTasks()
    {
        IList<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        using (var context = new MyDBContext(ConnectionString))
        {
           tasks = (from emp in context.Tasks select emp).ToList();
        }
        return tasks;
    }
```

this code return all posts from the database.

**My questions:**

- **1)** How I can get posts, for example, only with a specific date (datetime) or ID(int)?
- **2)** Is there any way to delete posts from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
tasks = from emp in context.Tasks 
        where emp.ID == yourId
        select emp;
```

To delete posts from te databse use [`DeleteOnSubmit(entity)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763473.aspx) method like:

```
context.Tasks.Attach(entityToDelete);
context.Tasks.DeleteOnSubmit(entityToDelete);
context.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You should add 'where' to your LINQ statement. Like this:

```
from emp in context.Tasks select emp where emp.Date == new DateTime(2011, 11, 11)
```

2) To delete posts from database you should do three simple steps:

1. Get posts you want to delete from db

   `tasks = from emp in context.Tasks select emp where emp.Date > new DateTime(2011, 11, 11)`
2. Call DeleteAllOnSubmit method of your DataContext object with our tasks to delete

   `dbContext.DeleteAllOnSubmit(tasks);`
3. Call SubmitChahges method of your DataContext object.

   `dbContext.SubmitChanges();`